# Cannot assign a device to node

Tags: python, tensorflow

I followed [this tutoriel](https://medium.com/@hamedmp/exporting-trained-tensorflow-models-to-c-the-right-way-cf24b609d183#.qajf9shah) to export my own trained tensorflow model to c++ and I got errors when I call [`freeze_graph`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py#L70)

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:838] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: TITAN X (Pascal), pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0)
...
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device to node 'save/Const_1': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
Colocation Debug Info:
Colocation group had the following types and devices: 
Identity: CPU 
Const: CPU 
     [[Node: save/Const_1 = Const[dtype=DT_STRING, value=Tensor<type: string shape: [] values: model>, _device="/device:GPU:0"]()]]
Caused by op u'save/Const_1', defined at:
...
```

*GPU:0* is detected and usable by Tensorflow, so I don't understand from where the error comes from.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means op `save/Const_1` is trying to get placed on GPU, and there's no GPU implementation of that node. In fact `Const` nodes are CPU only and are stored as part of Graph object, so it can't be placed on GPU. One work-around is to run with `allow_soft_placement=True`, or to open the `pbtxt` file and manually remove the `device` line for that node